# Add another program to Windows utility manager

Tags: windows

I am wondering whether i can develop an application similar to Ubuntu where anyone can drop a message to the user even the System is locked. i've tried several ways but failed to find a good solution. i think i can implement this by adding an application to Utility manager. do anyone have any idea of how to add it to utility manager or any other idea to implement it.

Thank you....